# How can I deal with a sudden loss of a clustered node using the low level .net Elasticsearch client?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have set up a cluster of three elastic search nodes all master eligible with 2 being the minimum required.  I have configured a client to then bulk upload using the low level client with a static connection pool using the code below.

What I am trying to test is live fail over scenarios i.e. start client with three nodes available and then randomly drop one (shutting down the VM), but keep two up.  However I am not seeing the behavior I would expect, it keeps trying the dead node. It actually it seems to take up to about sixty seconds before it moves to the next node.

What I would expect is it to do is to take a the failed attempt and mark that node as potentially dead but at least move on to the next node.  What is odd is this is the behavior I get if I start my application with only two of the three nodes available in my list or if I just stop the elastic search service during a test rather than a power down.

Is there a correct way to deal with such a case and get it to move to the next available node as quickly as possible?  Or do I need to potentially back off in my code for up to sixty seconds before attempting a republication?

```
var nodes = new[]
        {
            new Node(new Uri("http://172.16.2.10:9200")),
            new Node(new Uri("http://172.16.2.11:9200")),
            new Node(new Uri("http://172.16.2.12:9200"))
        };

        var connectionPool = new StaticConnectionPool(nodes);

        var settings = new ConnectionConfiguration(connectionPool)
            .PingTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
            .RequestTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20))
            .ThrowExceptions()
            .MaximumRetries(3);

        _lowLevelClient = new ElasticLowLevelClient(settings);
```

The following I then have wrapped in a try catch where I retry for a maximum of three times before I consider it a failed attempt and revert to an error strategy.

```
ElasticsearchResponse<Stream> indexResponse = _lowLevelClient.Bulk<Stream>(data);
```

Any input is appreciated,

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to replace StaticConnectionPool with SniffingConnectionPool (a sniffing connection pool allows itself to be reseeded at run time) ?   refer to : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/connection-pooling.html

Answer (score 0):

The tests for the client include tests for failover scenarios from which [the API conventions documentation is generated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/api-conventions.html). Specifically, take a look at the [retry](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/retries.html) and [failover](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/fail-over.html) documentation

With a `StaticConnectionPool`, the nodes to which requests can be made are static and never refreshed to reflect nodes that may join and leave the cluster, **but** they will be marked as being *dead* if a *bad response* is returned, and will be taken out of rotation for executing requests on for a configurable *dead* time, controlled by `DeadTimeout` and `MaxDeadTimeout` on connection settings.

The audit trail on the response should provide a timeline of what has happened for a given request, which is easiest to see with `response.DebugInformation`. The Virtual Clustering test harness ([an example](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/626835383fbeec5523da59bd2aa09cfb4a0a4dc5/src/Tests/ClientConcepts/ConnectionPooling/MaxRetries/RespectsMaxRetry.doc.cs#L20-L52)) that are part of the Tests project may help to ascertain the correct settings for the behaviour you're after.

Comment: Thanks, I played about with those timeout settings, defaulting back to the 60 second timeout.  Along with having my own try catch / retry logic I can get my request to eventually succeed on a sudden node loss.  However I some how feel there is something in the background that is determining the node as dead and not the failed publish attempt as the times don't correlate for me.  I notice the timeout will happen after 60 seconds and the successful publish will occur approx 20 seconds into my retry.  Perhaps there is some negotiation that must happen with the nodes before they will allow a it?